# Redux helper function to check if a value is in the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a filter panel where the user can select different color filters:

```
// ColorButton.jsx
function ColorButton({ color }) {

 const handleFilterSelected = ({ id }) => {
    dispatch(applyFilter({ type: "colors", value: id }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="color-button" onClick={() => handleFilterSelected(color)}>
      {isFilterSelected({ type: "colors", value: color.id }) ? "yay" : "nay"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The selected filters are stored in the redux store and the `isFilterSelect` function looks like this:

```js
// redux/utils/filter.utils.js
export const isFilterSelected = ({ type, value }) => {
  const {
    filters: { applied }
  } = store.getState();

  return applied
    .filter((f) => f.type === type)
    .map((f) => f.value)
    .includes(value);
};
```

The issue is that the check runs *before* a selected filter is added to the `applied` array.

As a more general question - is it even a good idea to have "helper" functions that depend on the redux store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper function there should be written as a selector that gets the current state, and you should be using `useSelector` instead of `store.getState` manually, as that will update your component when the selector value changes.

```js
function ColorButton({ color }) {
  const isSelected = useSelector(state => isFilterSelected(state, { type: "colors", value: color.id }));
  return (
    <div className="color-button">
      {isSelected ? "yay" : "nay"}
    </div>
  );
}


// redux/utils/filter.utils.js
export const isFilterSelected = (state, { type, value }) => {
  return state.filters.applied
    .filter((f) => f.type === type)
    .map((f) => f.value)
    .includes(value);
};
```